# Send update ping to ping services in Terminal?

Tags: terminal, ping

I want to send ping from `http://www.mysite.com/rss.xml` to `http://rpc.pingomatic.com`

Is there any way using terminal to achieve this?

Comment: Going to [http://rpc.pingomatic.com/](http://rpc.pingomatic.com/) with a web-broswer shows "XML-RPC server accepts POST requests only./". I suspect you don't want to ping it, you want to send an http POST.

Comment: Most people use Wordpress built-in ping. But that ping is not so good since I unable choose time to ping. Browsing pingomatic website and submit my blog manually is worse, it will will make our life more difficult and waste more time. I'm not so great with php, so I'm looking for other choice

Comment: See this answer from stackoverflow :[http://stackoverflow.com/a/2219094](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2219094). It looks like you can submit your site once manually then just access the resulting URL to update. You could then copy this URL and access it with `wget` via a cronjob.